# JS focus и blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, blur

Здравствуйте!
Я использую focus, чтобы запускать setInterval и blur чтобы его останавливать. Всё работает хорошо, за исключением того что нужно сначала кликнуть по сайту, чтобы всё начало работать. Можно ли по умолчанию сделать фокус на окне? Буду рад любой помощи или предложениям по доработке скрипта.

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

var $frame = $('.man-frames'),
    frames = [
        {default: {top: 30, left: -150}, animate: {left: 0}},
        {default: {top: '50%', left: -150}, animate: {left: 0}},
        {default: {left: -150, bottom: 10}, animate: {left: 0}},
        {default: {top: -150, right: 0, left: 'auto', transform: 'rotate(90deg)'}, animate: {top: 0}},
        {default: {bottom: 0, right: -150, left: 'auto', transform: 'rotate(-180deg)'}, animate: {right: 0}},
        {default: {bottom: '50%', right: -150, left: 'auto', transform: 'rotate(-180deg)'}, animate: {right: 0}},
        {default: {left: '50%', top: -150, transform: 'rotate(90deg)'}, animate: {top: 0}},
        {default: {left: '20%', bottom: -150, transform: 'rotate(-90deg)'}, animate: {bottom: 0}},
        {default: {left: '60%', bottom: -150, transform: 'rotate(-90deg)'}, animate: {bottom: 0}}
    ];

var interval;

$(window).on("focus blur", function (e) {
    var prevType = $(this).data("prevType");

    if (prevType != e.type) {   //  reduce double fire issues
        switch (e.type) {
            case "focus":
                console.log('Активна');
                interval = setInterval(function () {
                    var frame = frames[getRandomInt(0, frames.length - 1)];
                    $frame
                        .removeAttr('style')
                        .css(frame.default)
                        .animate(frame.animate, 200, function () {
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                $frame.animate(frame.default);
                            }, 1000);
                        });
                }, 3000);
                break;
            case "blur":
                console.log('Не активна');
                clearInterval(interval);
                break;
        }
    }

    $(this).data("prevType", e.type);
});
```

Comment: Добавить в конце `$(window).focus()`

Comment: @br3t Пробовал. После загрузки фокус всё-равно не происходит. Добавлял сразу после скрипта. Проверяю в хроме. Нужно сначала сделать вкладку не активной, потом вернуться обратно...

Comment: Возможно можно это обыграть, если курсор попадает в зону сайта? Уже даже не знаю как сделать, чтобы работало правильно.

Comment: `$(window).on('mouseover', function() {
$(window).focus();
});` вариант с фокусом при ховере

Comment: @br3t большое спасибо за помощь, но к сожалению это мне не помогло :( Возможно я где-то ошибся в своём скрипте?

Всё работает, только если сделать вкладку неактивной, а потом вернуться обратно.

Comment: У меня вот так получилось https://jsfiddle.net/br3t/upn9vbvL/ , при блёре перестает "крутиться", а при ховере потом снова "крутится"

Comment: @br3t Да, вижу. По идее всё должно работать верно. Возможно это проблема браузера?

Comment: Может быть, с самим интервалом все в порядке, но у вас не работает что-то другое? Например, откуда в вашем коде берется `$frame`? Это всегда один и тот же фрейм?

Comment: @br3t Обновил код в вопросе.

Comment: Вроде работает https://jsfiddle.net/br3t/upn9vbvL/